# Unable to add fingerprint on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: drivers, fingerprint-reader, 23.04

I have my fingerprint available, but while enrolling it is not showing up.

```
ashish@ashish-BMH-WCX9:~$ sudo fprintd-enroll
Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
ashish@ashish-BMH-WCX9:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 27c6:5125 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix Fingerprint Device 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0489:e0df Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:56f9 IMC Networks ov9734_azurewave_camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:00ac Lite-On Technology Corp. Dell Wireless Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Sme here. It worked failry well with 22.04. Moreover, if I boot with 22.04 first then reboot without power off to 23.04 it sometimes works. It enrolls fingerprints, but first fails to verify then "looses" them like weren't enrolled: https://crypstie.com/_Gdy4hV2Ir7d#B3lHV2nS2iYkHYTrR_VhZsdpQ0QjR8VjLNqq0gG7kQE

Comment: For future readers of this issue, can you please include your laptop brand/model. Regarding your issue, it appears that your fingerprint hardware (`27c6:5125`) is not supported, per this page: https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html.

Comment: More tech info on the issue can be found here: https://crypstie.com/_EJNDM23lG1C#kZqZfUUERzUJxERLRO1.8NbacMhEPGJt_axG5FushkI